# How to force a derived class comparison

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a virtual `class Element` that forces its derived classes to have a == operator:

So, I have derived classes (Integer, Word) that implement that operator.

I have a `class Group` that basically is a list of elements.

In a function, I want to compare if an element from a group its equal to an element of a different group, so I'm using:

```
if(actual == lookingfor)
```

where both actual and lookingfor are pointers to Element...but the comparison is being made at the level of pointers, so both pointers are always different.

How can I force that the operator == from the derived class of element be used?

EDIT:

```
class Element 
{ 
  virtual int operator==(Elemento *)=0; 
}

class Word : public Element { ... } 

int Word::operator==(Element * element) 
{ 
  Element * ptr = element; 
  Word * wordPtr = dynamic_cast< Word * >(ptr); 
  int equal = 0; 
  if(wordPtr)
  { 
    equal = strncmp(this->ptr,wordPtr->ptr,49)==0; 
  } 
  return igual; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>please not that the below implementation uses references instead of pointers as arguments to `operator==` defined as *pure-abstract* in `struct Element`. This is how it's usually done and I'd recommend you to do the same in your code.</sup>

```
#include <iostream>

struct Element {
  virtual ~Element () {}
  virtual bool operator== (Element&) const =0; 
};

struct Integer : Element {
  bool operator== (Element&) const {
    return false; /* dummy impl */
  }
};

struct Word : Element {
  bool operator== (Element&) const {
    return false; /* dummy impl */
  }
};
```

---

It's not possible to overload the comparision of pointers in `C++`, you will have to dereference your pointers so that you'll get valid objects which you can compare in a normal manner, and your own `operator==` will be called.

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Element * e1 = new Integer;
  Element * e2 = new Word;

  if (*e1 == *e2)
    ;   

  delete e2; 
  delete e1; 
}
```

---

Another method is to call your `operator==` directly through your pointers, such as in the below example.

```
if (e1->operator== (*e2))
  ;
```

---

Comment: Thanks refp, I have to use pointers because I have to stick to the already written "Element.h" virtual 
int operator==(Elemento *)=0; 
and when I try to dereference I get an error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘*actual == * lookingfor’

Comment: It actually works using:
actual->operator==(lookingfor)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that the == operator will quite do what you want here, but you could always define a virtual method:

```
class Element {
[...]
   virtual IsEqualTo(const Element & rhs) const = 0;
};
```

... and then for each subclass, implement the method like this:

```
class Word : public Element {
[...]
   virtual IsEqualTo(const Element & rhs) const
   {
      const Word * wrhs = dynamic_cast<const Word *>(&rhs);
      return ((wrhs)&&(*wrhs == *this));
   }
};
```

... and then your Group method could either call IsEqualTo() directly on the various Elements in the Groups as necessary, or if you prefer to make it "pretty", you could implement Element::operator==(const Element &) to call IsEqualTo() internally instead, and have your Group methods (etc) call it, e.g.

```
bool Element :: operator == (const Element & rhs) const
{
   return IsEqualTo(rhs);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I have to stick to the already written "Element.h"
virtual int operator==(Elemento *)=0;

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sample code would be nice...

Deriving from the bits of information your code looks something like this

```
Group* group1 = new Group();
Group* group2 = new Group();

if ( group1 == group2 )
```

which is a pointer comparision. You have to compare the instances:

```
if ( *group1 == *group2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

> if(actual == lookingfor)
>
> where both actual and lookingfor are pointers to Element...but the comparison is being made 
>   at the level of pointers, so both pointers are always different.

You can't. Operators in C++ can be overloaded only when atleast one argument is user-defined types. The compiler will flag an error on anything else.

If you wish to compare in that case, you have to use:

```
if(*actual == *lookingfor) //for element-comparison
```

If you want to compare an array of pointers, or something like that you have to resort to writing your own code using loops.

What I suggest here is, why not use `std::vector<Element>` or any other suitable STL container?

Comment: Thanks, but when I use (*actual == *lookingfor) I get the following error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘*actual == * lookingfor’